# Query sql up to 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

My English is not good.
I need help with the sql query. My tables:

```
 color:
 +------------+----------------+
 | id_col     | int(11)        | // ID
 | ral        | int(4)         | // ID color
 | c_hex      | tinytext       | 
 | c_rgb      | tinytext       |
 +------------+----------------+
 alterna:
 +------------+----------------+
 | id_alt     | int(11)        | // ID
 | color      | int(4)         | // ID color from the previous table
 | alternativ | tinytext       | // value
 | a_range    | enum('0', '1') | // 0 - NCS, 1 - Pantone
 | a_rating   | int(1)         | // value
 +------------+----------------+
```

Example data:

```
 id_col     ral     c_rgb           c_hex
        1   1000    190-189-127     BEBD7F
        2   1001    194-176-120     C2B078
        3   1002    198-166-100     C6A664
        4   1003    229-190-001     E5BE01
        5   1004    205-164-052     CDA434

    id_alt  color   alternativ  a_range     a_rating
    1       1       4525 C      1           4
    2       1       2020-Y      0           4
    3       1       2020-G90Y   0           2
    6       1       2020-G80Y   0           1
    9       2       2020-Y20R   0           4
    10      2       7502 U      1           4
    11      2       7502 C      1           2
```

I would like to achieve this effect:

```
+---------+--------------+
|     ral | 1000         | // color from the first table
|     ncs | 2020-Y ****  | // alternative color (a_range=0, a_rating=4)
|         | 2020-G90Y ** | // alternative color (a_range=0, a_rating=2)
|         | 2020-G80Y *  | // alternative color (a_range=0, a_rating=1)
|         | 2020-Y10R *  | // alternative color (a_range=0, a_rating=1)
| pantone | 4525 C ****  | // alternative color (a_range=1, a_rating=4)
|         | 5855 C **    | // alternative color (a_range=1, a_rating=2)
|         | 4535 C **    | // alternative color (a_range=1, a_rating=2)
|         | 7502 C *     | // alternative color (a_range=1, a_rating=1)
|     rgb | 190-189-127  |
|     hex | BEBD7F       |
+---------+--------------+
```

My sql query does not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM color 
LEFT JOIN alterna ON color.id_col=alterna.color
```

I want to display data on the page using PHP ...

Comment: Result of SQL query is a table (set of rows).  The rest is front-end formatting.

Comment: your name  table is kolor or color???

Comment: It has to be color